# Identify missing mandatory tasks via lookup from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I have a table that gives me the mandatory tasks per plan

| Plan Type | Task |
| --- | --- |
| Electricity | Task1 |
| Electricity | Task2 |
| Plumbing | Task1 |

Then I have a table with the project plan. I want to make sure that all the mandatory tasks are included. So for the table below you can see that Task2 is missing for Electricity. We can have additional tasks, but the mandatory tasks need to be there.

| Project ID | Plan | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | Electricity | Task1 |
| 1002 | Electricity | Task3 |
| 1002 | Plumbing | Task1 |

In Power BI I would like to create a table as such:

Missing Mandatory Tasks:

| Project ID | Plan | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | Electricity | Task2 |

I've googled to find help with this question, but I'm stuck. Can anybody help?

Comment: I think you need to use EXCEPT(table1, table2)... the catch is that the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question. Really good exercise if you're new to the DAX set functions (UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT, CROSSJOIN).

Since DAX is funny in that it joins only on single columns, I created a calculated column in both the 'MandatoryTasks' and 'PlanTasks' tables

```
PlanTypeTask =  [Plan Type] & "\" & [Task]
```

So the tables now look like this: MandatoryTasks(Plan Type, Task, PlanTypeTask)

```
DISTINCT('Projects'[ProjectName])
```

Now that I have those two tables, I can crossjoin them (creates a Cartesian Product... all possible combinations of the two sets of values).

```
AllProjectTasks = CROSSJOIN(VALUES('Projects'[ProjectName]),'MandatoryTasks')
```

Then I just subtract.

```
EXCEPT('AllProjectTasks','ProjectPlan')
```

Comment: Good solution but your answer could be clearer as it will be difficult for OP to follow. Add screenshots at each stage if you can.

Comment: Sorry about that, I figured out at some crazy hour of night and was too tired to do all the documentation. I'll sort out the whole thing with hopefully step by step instructions, because the solution wasn't super obvious.